# Export Hive data incremental

Tags: hive, sqoop

We have a requirement to run HiveQL incrementally and export results to a file in avro fromat, and we need to export the records.

Following are the 2 ways i am looking at and challenges i see in using them.

Option 1: using Pig and customer loader: 
      a. Writing a custom pig loader which run the hive query incemental.
      b. write a pig flow and create a relation to the results of hive loader. 
      c. save the result in avro file.

Option 2. SQOOP export - i couldn't find a why to export hive query results in        incrementally.

So far with my analysis i am think going with option 1 will better suit for my requirement.

Can someone please explain if you think we can acheive this easily in sqoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqoop can export data from HDFS directory to target databases, not files. In this case sqoop cannot

1. Read increment results unless you have separate hive table or partition (which results in new directory)
2. Write into external files in avro format.

Comment: thanks! Do you see any other ways to acheive my requirement ?